# Css3 Media query for responsive versions

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using some media queries for responsive versions, but with the smallest screen media query it breaks the whole code.

This is the structure of my media query!

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */*1
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

/* All Smartphones in portrait and landscape ----------- */*2
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 479px) {
/* Styles */

/***** For HTC Mobile *******/*3
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 320px) {
```

With the above structure, the 3rd one media query isn't good at all.

I wrote following code in my style sheet with 3rd one media query.

```
/***** For HTC Mobile *******/*3
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 320px) {

.module-title {
font-size: 25px !important;
line-height: 25px;


}
}
```

And this code is making title of all versions into font-size 25.

Why is this not specific only for small screens and why it's taking effect on all versions?

And also, should I use **"!important"** on all versions for all classes?

**like:**

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */*1
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

.module-title: 30px !important;

}

}
/* All Smartphones in portrait and landscape ----------- */*2
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 479px) {
/* Styles */
.module-title: 27px !important;

}
}

/***** For HTC Mobile *******/*3
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 320px) {

.module-title: 30px !important;
}
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your CSS does not validate.

Comment: it is validated with 26 minor errors of webkit and moz!

Comment: Avoid use of `!important` **whenever possible**.  You should resort to well-designed markup and selector specificity instead.  `!important` styles are the most specific of all and override ALL other styles, including inline styles and IDs.  In general it's sloppy and a pain to maintain and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: `.module-title: 30px !important;` what is 30px? you can't give properties to selectors... minor errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `!important` from the non-responsive class. and make sure you're closing media queries properly.

**Example:**

```
@media (max-width: 300px {

/*styles goes here*/
.tag {
} This is tag closing
} this is query closing
```

Comment: i am using media @ keyframes with double }} at the end, it is the single code with double brackets? is this making my code bad?

Comment: Maybe Yes or you are using more extra brackets in your code, remove additional bracket and close it again at the end of the query code! hope this helps!

Comment: Amazing :) I removed extra brackets and everything works great now. Actually, that @keyframes were making mess with code with double brackets but now its works like charm :) Thank you so much –

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is very wrong:

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */*1
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 479px) {
/* Styles */
.module-title: 27px !important;

}
}
```

...because you can't just give a property to a selector!

The `*1` after the comment above the code is ***outside the comment***.

So the problem is that and the double braces. The `!important` below would only break other query if any of the conditions were met in other `media-queries` (`only screen`, `min-width: 321px` or `max-width: 479`).

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    .module-title { font-size: 27px !important; }
}
```

It would not influence the media-query below, for instance:

```
@media only print and (min-width: 480px) {
    .module-title { font-size: 27px; }
}
```

The syntax above would be the correct one.